# Unable to check int array inside a lambda expression

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, lambda

I tried to check `score[0]` :

> if score[0] is 1 , pos+1
>
> if score[0] is 0 ,neu+1
>
> if score[0] is -1, neg+1

```
final int[] score = { 0 };
final  int post = 0;
final int neu = 0;
final int neg = 0;
stream.forEach(line -> {

    ps.println("Code: " + analysis.parse(line).getCode()); 
    score[0] = score[0] + analysis.parse(line).getCode(); 

    if(score[0]==1){ post ++;}   //problem line
    else if (score[0]==0) {neu++;}  //problem line 
    else{ neg++; }  //problem line 
});
```

## update

I tried to remove `final` in the variable initiation

> local variable referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

## sample code

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    final int[] score = { 0 };
    int post = 0;

    try (Stream < String > stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("e:\\in.txt")).sequential()) { //retrieve txt file
        File file = new File("e:\\out.txt"); //output file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);

        stream.forEach(line -> {
            if(score[0]==1){ post ++;}
        });

        System.out.println("postive=" + post); 
    }
}
```

## purpose

I tried to read txt file by line.

Then, I use an external library to translate every line into code (-1,0,1)

The codes in every lines store in score[0]

I create `pos` `neu` `neg` to count how many `-1,0,1` respectively.

More importantly, the problem I m facing is the part of checking `-1/0/1`. Other parts should be fine.

Lastly, the translated codes will output to a new txt, including the value of `pos,neu,neg`.

Originally code :

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    final int[] score = { 0 };
    int post = 0;
    final int neu = 0;
    final int neg =    0;

    try (Stream < String > stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("e:\\ust.txt")).sequential()) { //retrieve txt file
        File file = new File("e:\\gg.txt"); //output file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);
        final Analysis analysis = new Analysis();
        stream.forEach(line -> {

            ps.println("Code: " + analysis.parse(line).getCode()); //show current line's code
            score[0] = score[0] + analysis.parse(line).getCode();  //add up total codes
            if(analysis.parse(line).getCode()==1){ post ++;}  // check current codes=>line with problems
            else if (analysis.parse(line).getCode()==0) {neu++;}// check current codes=>line with problems
            else{ neg++; } //check current codes=> line with problems

        });

        System.out.println("score=" + score[0]); //print out the total score
        System.out.println("postive=" + post); 
        System.out.println("neu=" + neu); 
        System.out.println("neg=" + neg); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't mutate the value of finals in Java

Comment: @mre Updated ..

Comment: can you provide us with a short, _compilable_ example?

Comment: @mre updated ...

Comment: This question is very unclear, and it would be better if you first explained what you are trying to do, before you show how you have incorrectly approached it. It looks like you are trying to perform some sort of [*reduction*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) over the stream. Or in other words, read the file, and update three variables (`pos`, `neg`, and `neu`) based on what you read from each line. Is that right?

Comment: Also, why use `Stream` instead of a loop here? Is it a requirement for homework? And do you really intend to add the code for each line to the "current" score? That is, which of the three variables to increment depends on previous values as well as the current line? Explaining the problem in addition to your code helps a lot.

Comment: @erickson updated

Comment: There is a fundamental logic error in the line `score[0] = score[0] + analysis.parse(line).getCode();`. You are summing up the values, which contradicts your task description—why are you doing this?

Comment: @Holger Yes , I made logical error . I updated the code .The problems still exist

Comment: You still have multiple copies of that erroneous code. If you remove the summing behavior, the entire array becomes obsolete. Besides that, the problem only keeps existing, because you are ignoring the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to modify a method variable inside a lambda, but Java does not allow that (the variable must be final or effectively final).

The solution I have used in the past is to use `AtomicInteger`. In your case:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    final int[] score = { 0 };
    final AtomicInteger post = new AtomicInteger(0); // this object will be final, but its contents can be modified inside the lambda

    try (Stream < String > stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("e:\\in.txt")).sequential()) { //retrieve txt file
        File file = new File("e:\\out.txt"); //output file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);

        stream.forEach(line -> {
            if(score[0]==1) { post.incrementAndGet(); }
        });

        System.out.println("postive=" + post.get()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the occurrences of different codes in the stream by grouping and counting, like this:

```
Collector<Integer, ?, Map<Integer, Long>> counter = 
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.counting());
Map<Integer, Long> countByCode = lines
    .map(l -> analysis.parse(l).getCode())
    .collect(counter);
System.out.println(countByCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to solve a problem using the Stream API, you should stop searching for solutions using `forEach`. A [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) has quite a few other methods to offer. If none of them helps reaching your goal, you should consider staying with an ordinary loop.

But you may also read the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) or [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) to find ways to break out of the thinking in loops/`forEach`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    long pos, neu, neg;
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("e:\\out.txt");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos)) {

        try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("e:\\in.txt"))) {
            Map<Integer, Long> m = stream
                .map(line -> analysis.parse(line).getCode())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));

            pos = m.get(+1);
            neu = m.get( 0);
            neg = m.get(-1);
        }
        ps.println("pos="+pos);
        ps.println("neu="+neu);
        ps.println("neg="+neg);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ps.println("pos="+pos);//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: You can’t get a `NullPointerException` at this point, if you use the code as written in my answer. Only `ps` is dereferenced in that line and since it contains the result of the `new` operator (`new PrintStream(fos)`), it can not be `null`. Being a resource in a `try(…)` statement, you can’t even change it to `null` after the creation.

Comment: Yes , I mix up the `input.txt` & `output.txt` .All 3 ans should be correct here . Can you comment the others answer here ?

Comment: well, if you go through the answers, trying to understand what they are doing, you’ll find that erickson’s answer has an approach close to mine, whereas Jason’s answer focuses on making your question’s original code work, however, in the end it’s not recommended to solve your task in this way. You may follow the links I provided in my answer or search other, related SO questions to find more about the topic.